# First use in this function

Tags: c, function, undefined, undeclared-identifier

I started learning C recently, and whenever I try to run this it's giving an error of "a" and "b" undeclared as first use in this function, even, though the course I was watching ran the same code with no erros, he just changed the number to 10 and 15 thats all

```
#define sum (a,b)(printf("%i", a + b));
int main ()
{

the enitre code is 

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define Name "JSDJSDJ"
#define Age 3000
#define sum (a,b) (printf("%i",a + b));

int main ()
{
    sum(100,150);
    printf ("%i", Age);

    return 0;
}
    sum (100,150);
}
```

Not much other than changing the numbers

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/249845/discussion-on-question-by-absolutenothing-first-use-in-this-function).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you define a macro with parameters, you can't have spaces between the macro name and `(`. This is an exception to the usual rule that whitespace is insignificant between tokens in C, because the preprocessor needs to be able to distinguish between a function-like macro and a macro that expands into something surrounded by `()`.

So it should be

```
#define sum(a,b) (printf("%i", (a) + (b)));
```

You should also always wrap macro parameters in parentheses in the replacement list, to avoid problems with operator precedence when the argument is an expression.

Comment: And it's a very common convention to capitalise macro names, e.g.: `SUM`.  I like to use the convention of prefixing any with `MACRO_`, so _when_ it goes wrong, it's easier to debug.

Comment: I thought C doesn't really care about spacing but thank you so much

Comment: @AbsoluteNothing Well, the language of the [C preprocessor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C_preprocessor) isn't really C.

Comment: @AbsoluteNothing that's not C. As people point out, that's a preprocessor macro, which you're abusing here to write something that looks like a function. I really don't know from what you're learning this, but you really should not be taught C looks like this - as you can see yourself, it's not really C, and fragile.

Comment: @Bob__: The C standard includes and specifies preprocessing as part of the C language, in clause 6.10. A C implementation without preprocessing would not be standard C.

Comment: @MarcusMüller: Preprocessing is C. The C standard includes and specifies preprocessing as part of the C language, in clause 6.10. A C implementation without preprocessing would not be standard C.

Comment: @AbsoluteNothing As I said, this is an exception. The preprocessor has different rules from the main language grammar, just as printf format strings do.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want a 'function' then the code should look like this

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#define Name "JSDJSDJ"
#define Age 3000

void sum (int a, int b){
 printf("%i",a + b));
}

int main ()
{
    sum(100,150);
    printf ("%i", Age);

    return 0;
 }
```

Comment: @AbsoluteNothing - you need to understand that a function is a completely different thing from a macro. You should almost always use functions for things like this